# How to pass options to class in a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, es6-class

There is a class that creates container. I use it twice to create 2 containers, but I want to use it only once (and still create 2 containers). When I put `new Container()` inside class method, infinite loop appears (what is obvious). How to make class make another (the same) one?

I bet it's possible. If so, is there a possibility of passing `settings` to second class, but **NOT** in a parameter? Maybe another method of first class which I can use in second class, but which uses `this.options` from first class?

To make things clear, by "first class" I mean first run of `Container` class and by "second class"- another `Container class` created inside first.

https://jsfiddle.net/rqhwsv2p/5/

```
class Container {
    constructor(element, className, settings) {
        this.init(element, className, settings);
    }

    init(element, className, settings) {
        var template = '<div class=' + className + '></div>';
        var container = $(template);

        element.append(container);

        if (settings) {
            this.settings = settings;

            this.getSettings();
            console.log('settings:::::', this.settings);
        }
    }

    getSettings() {
        return this.settings;
    }
}

var body = $('body');
var settingsOuter = {enable: true, visible: true, color: true};

var outer = new Container(body, 'container', settingsOuter);
var inner = new Container($('.container'), 'inner-container');
```

Comment: Would the second container being a property of the first one be okay? How exactly do you plan to access that second container? Also, how does the first container know which parameters to pass over to the second one? Please give more details/examples.

Comment: Let's try with the property. I gave an example where one is inside of another (`inner-container` inside of `container)`, but it can also be a second append to body. It doesn't matter, it probably works the same. I need to pass only `options`.

Comment: By `options` do you mean `settings`? Cause I don't see any `options` anywhere in the code you posted. Also in your example, you're passing `$('.container')` and `'inner-container'` as arguments to the second container. How can the outer container know to pass them to the inner one?

Comment: Yes, I meant `settings`, sorry. As I told you, passed arguments are just example. You can use `body` in each run of a class. Second argument is example element class. Each run of a class means `new className(arguments)` right? So, in my example, there are passed arguments, there are not any special ones. I don't understand your point of view.

Comment: Guess I'm missing something, but looks like @guest271314's figured something out so it's all fine :)

Comment: So you want to pass the same settings to both `new Container` calls? Just do it, you already got the `settingsOuter` in a reusable variable. I don't see any reason to avoid passing them as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

You can define `settings` as a default parameter of the `class` `constructor`

```
class Container {
    constructor(element, className, settings = {enable: true, visible: true, color: true}) {
        this.init(element, className, settings);
    }

    init(element, className, settings) {
        var template = '<div class=' + className + '></div>';
        var container = $(template);

        element.append(container);

        if (settings) {
            this.settings = settings;

            this.getSettings();
            console.log('settings:::::', this.settings);
        } else {
            this.settings = void 0;
        }
    }

    getSettings() {
        return this.settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I cannot. Each element is meant to have it's own options. I need to get settings from the first class and implement some of them (which I do not have in 2nd) in second.

Comment: @hames The default parameter can be the default behaviour, having no effect on the element, only when the property values of the object passed differ from the default parameter will those specific property values be changed. To use the settings of the first created class you can use `var inner = new Container($('.container'), 'inner-container', outer.getSettings())`

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's the one way. But is it possible to do it in other way than by passing it in an class argument?

Comment: @hames There are several approaches which can be used to achieve the expected result. You can `.push()` each `new Container()` to an array and get the `settings` from the last element of the array. Though if the same `settings` are used for each `new Container()` instance you can simply use the same `settingsOuter` variable.

Comment: @hames For what reasons? If the same `settings` are used for each `new Container()` instance you can simply use the same `settingsOuter` variable. Can you create a stacksnippet to demonstrate exactly what you are trying to achieve?